# upper bound for variance when using estimated values

Tags: probability, statistics

Let’s say I have a parameterspace $\Omega$ with known probability density function $p(\omega), \omega \in \Omega$. I want to estimate the expectation $E[x]$ of a variable $x$ depending on $\omega \in \Omega$.  I cannot calculate directly $x$ but I can make an estimation $\tilde{x}$ such that $\tilde{x}- x \leq \epsilon, \epsilon >  0$ and $x \leq \tilde{x}$.

It’s easy to prove that $|E[\tilde{x}] – E[x]| \leq \epsilon$. Is there a way to calculate a similar upper bound for  $|Var[\tilde{x}] – Var[x] |$?

Kind regards,
Koen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x]-\mathsf{Var}[x]
&=&
\mathsf{Var}[x+(\tilde x-x)]-\mathsf{Var}[x]
\\
&=&
\mathsf{Var}[x]+\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x-x]+2\mathsf{Cov}[x,\tilde x-x]-\mathsf{Var}[x]
\\
&=&
\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x-x]+2\mathsf{Cov}[x,\tilde x-x]
\\
&\le&
2\epsilon\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}[x]}+\epsilon^2\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

A slightly more natural and perhaps more useful result might be

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x]}{\mathsf{Var}[x]}
&=&
\frac{\mathsf{Var}[x+(\tilde x-x)]}{\mathsf{Var}[x]}
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathsf{Var}[x]+\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x-x]+2\mathsf{Cov}[x,\tilde x-x]}{\mathsf{Var}[x]}
\\
&\le&
1+2\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}[x]}}+\left(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}[x]}}\right)^2\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

(I left out all the absolute values signs for readability, but the inequality still holds if you add them.)

Comment: Can you explain why $\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x-x]+2\mathsf{Cov}[x,\tilde x-x] \leq 2\epsilon\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}[x]}+\epsilon^2$?  (the inequality in the first part)

Comment: @Koen: $\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x-x]\leq\epsilon^2$ is an immediate consequence of $|\tilde{x}-x|\leq\epsilon$, and $\mathsf{Cov}[x,\tilde x-x]\leq\epsilon\sqrt{\mathsf{Var}[x]}$ is a form of the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality); see [here in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Relationship_to_inner_products).

Comment: I think $\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x-x]\leq\epsilon^2$ is not in general true if $|\tilde{x}-x|\leq\epsilon$. Check the example: $x = \{1, 2\}, \epsilon = 0.5$ and $\tilde x = x + \{\epsilon, -\epsilon\} = \{1.5, 1.5\}$, then $\mathsf{Var}[\tilde x-x] = 0.5$ while $\epsilon^2 = 0.25$ (just assume that the probability on both elements in $x$ is 0.5)

Comment: @Koen: Perhaps you're confusing the variance with the standard variation? The variance in your example is $\epsilon^2=0.25$; the standard variation, the square root of the variance, is $\epsilon=0.5$.

Comment: Ok, you're right,